# how to validate New-ssh Session in Powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, ssh

I have downloaded SSH-Sessions by Joakim Svendsen which uses SSH.NET and installed the PowerShell module in the Jenkins Windows server

In Jenkins, I have the following PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module SSH-Sessions

$lastExitCode = 0
$devApp1 = "10.0.1.109"
$devApp2 = "10.0.1.110"

Write-Output "Deployment started in $devApp1......"

New-SshSession -ComputerName $devApp1 -Username test -Password test@123
```

The problem is that the Jenkins job doesn't get failed when the connectivity fails. The Jenkins output is:

> ```
> Unable to connect to 10.0.1.109: Exception calling "Connect" with "0" argumen
> t(s): "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused 
> it"
> Finished: SUCCESS
> ```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the module or Jenkins, but my guess is that Jenkins runs something like `powershell.exe -File your-script.ps1` and looks at the exit code. The issue might be that the error you see isn't a terminating one. You could try to add this to your script: `Set-Variable -Name "ErrorActionPreference" -Scope "Script" -Value "Stop"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this documentation](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library#New-SshSession), I would do something like this:

```
New-SshSession -ComputerName $devApp1 -Username test -Password test@123

if (!$SshSessions.$devApp1.Connected) {
    throw "Session to $devApp1 is not connected"
}
```

Or this:

```
New-SshSession -ComputerName $devApp1 -Username test -Password test@123    
$Session = Get-SshSession -ComputerName $devApp1

if (!$Session.Connected) {
    throw "Session to $devApp1 is not connected"
}
```

Obviously, if you've got multiple connections to `$devApp1` this code will not work, but the examples in the doc suggest it won't allow you to do that.  For whatever reason `New-SshSession` doesn't support the `-PassThru` parameter, nor does it seem to return the session, nor does it allow you to specify a variable for the session.  Instead the design uses a global variable: `$SshSessions`.  Not the way I'd design it.

You might want to look into [Posh-SSH](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH).  I don't remember if that is designed better, but I don't remember this kind of issue.  It also uses the SSH.Net library.  Alternately, [WinSCP has a .Net assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell) that is very easy to use from PowerShell.